# Characterization of arithmetic mean

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

Let $f_m$: $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^m \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be a series of functions that satisfy symmetry (when permuting indices), strong monotonicity (in every entry), homogeneity of degree 1,

$f_2(0,1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and for all $k<m$: $f_m(x)=f_m(f_k(x_1,...,x_k),...,f_k(x_1,...,x_k),x_{k+1},...,x_m)$

Show that for all $m$, $\;\; f_m(x)=\frac{x_1+...x_m}{m}$.

**My attempt:**

By homogeneity $f_2(x,0)=f_2(0,x)=xf_2(0,1)=\frac{x}{2}$. I noticed 
$f_1=$id, since $f_2(x,0)=f_2(f_1(x),0)$ implies $f_1(x)=x$: Indeed, injectivity in every entry follows from strong monotonicity: if by contrary $f_1(x)>x$ then $f_2(f_1(x),0)>f_2(x,0)$, and similarly we can't have $f_1(x)<x$, so $f_1(x)=x$ for all x.

I couldn't get any further,though: it seems impossible to use it to conclude anything decisive about the higher m's.

Without the "boundary condition", the set of solutions is closed under addition. But it isn't closed under subtraction , so it doesn't help.

Comment: Insufficient effort on part of OP: he's just dumping a pretty large question on SE users.

Comment: There seems to be a notational problem.  As indicated $f_k$ should take $k$ arguments, so presumably each invocation of $f_k(x)$ is meant to be $f_k(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ or something that provides the required number of arguments.

Comment: @hardmath I added the attempt in the post and removed any chance of ambiguity.

Comment: @Phira It was on a (non-web) page consisting of several hard olympiad problems – I couldn't find which one that's from. I didn't advance at all playing with $f_4$.

Comment: The fact $f_1(x)=x$ follows directly from homogeneity and $f_2(x,0)=f_2(f_1(x),0)$ since then $xf_2(1,0)=f_1(x)f_2(1,0).$

Comment: it seems like @Phira has deleted his comment, indicating the hint was probably false. So no solution yet?

Comment: @Leullame I deleted my comment because I realized that it was more complicated than I thought, and my solution is only vaguely related to my hint (which was "look at $f_4$ before you look at $f_3$" for the record).

Comment: @Leullame Also, I am female.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $f_m(x,x,x,\dots,x)=x$ (in particular $f_1(x)=x$)

We calculate $C_m=f_m(1,1,1, \dots)$:

$C_{2m}=f_{2m}(1,1,\dots)=f_{2m}(f_m(1,1,\dots,),\dots)= C_m C_{2m}$

The monotonicity ensures that $C_{2m}\not=0$, so we get $C_m=1$ for all $m$, homogeneity immediately implies $f_m(x,x,\dots,x)=x$.

> For $d_m=f_m(1,0,\dots,0)$ we have $d_ad_b=d_{ab}$ for natural numbers $a,b$.

$$d_{ab}=f_{ab}(1,0,\dots,0)=f_{ab}(f_a(1,0,\dots,0),\dots,f_a(1,0,\dots,0),0,\dots,0)=d_a f_{ab}(f_b(1,0,\dots,0),\dots,f_b(1,0,\dots,0))=d_ad_bf_{ab}(1,\dots,1)=d_ad_b$$

> For $d_m=f_m(1,0,\dots,0)$, we have $d_m < d_{m-1}$ for all positive $m$.

$$d_m=f_m(1,0,\dots,0)=f_m(f_{m-1}(1,0,\dots,0),\dots,f_{m-1}(1,0,\dots,0),0)=d_{m-1}f_m(1,\dots,1,0)<d_{m-1}f_m(1,\dots,1)=d_{m-1}.$$

> The initial conditions $d_1=1$, $d_2=\frac12$, the multiplicativity and the monotonous descent give $d_m=\frac1m$.

For given integers $m$ and $k$, choose $l$ so that $$2^l\le m^k < 2^{l+1},$$ that is $l=\lfloor k \log_2(m)\rfloor$.

We know that
$$d_{2^l} \ge d_{m^k} > d_{2^{l+1}}$$ which implies
$$ 2^l \le \frac 1 {d_m^k} < 2^{l+1}.$$

Therefore, $l=\lfloor k \log_2(\frac 1{d_m})\rfloor$ and we get for all $k \in \mathbb N$:
$$\lfloor k \log_2(m)\rfloor = \lfloor k \log_2(\frac 1{d_m})\rfloor$$

This implies $m=\frac 1{d_m}$ and we are done. (Just choose powers of ten for $k$ to see that the two logarithms share arbitrarily many decimals.)

> $f_2(x,y)=\frac{x+y}2$

Let $a,b$ be two positive integers.
$$\frac1{a+b}2f_2(a,b)=d_{a+b}2f_2(a,b)= 2f_2(a,b)f_{a+b}(1,0,\dots,0)=2f_2(a,b)f_{a+b}(\frac12,\frac12,0,\dots,0)=
f_{a+b}(a,b,0,0,\dots)=f_{a+b}(f_a(a,0,0,\dots),\dots,f_b(b,0,0,\dots))=f_{a+b}(1,1,\dots)=1.$$

Therefore, $f_2(a,b)=\frac{a+b}2$ for any positive integers $a,b$.
By homogeneity, $f_2(1,z)=\frac{1+z}2$ for any positive rational $z$.

Monotonicity immediately implies that the identity is true for any positive real $z$. Homogeneity gives the desired result for $f_2(x,y)$.

> $f_m(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m) = \dfrac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_m}m$

$$f_m(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m)= f_m(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{m-2},\frac{x_{m-1}+x_m}2,\frac{x_{m-1}+x_m}2)=f_m(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{m-2},x_{m-1}+x_m,0)=f_m(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{m-2}+x_{m-1}+x_m,0,0)=\dots=f_m(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_m,0,\dots,0)=\dfrac{x_1+x_2+\dots +x_m}m.$$

> Remark

The same proof should work for other means like the quadratic mean if we choose the normalization of $f_2$ to correspond to it.

Comment: 1)How did you change two arguments into their sum and zero? $f_m(x_1,\dots,x_{m-2},\frac{x_{m-1}+x_m}2,
\frac{x_{m-1}+x_{m}}2) =f_m(x_1,\dots,x_{m-2},x_{m-1}+x_m,0)$
2)What intuition leads to finding $d_m$? (Is the logarithmic method general for multiplicative series?)

Comment: @Leullame Apply $f_2(x_{m-1}+x_{m},0) =\frac{x_{m-1}+x_m}2$ to the last two arguments. As for the intuition, I did the calculation from the $f_2(x,y)$ paragraph very early on, so I knew I would be done if I could evaluate $f_m(1,0,\dots,0)$. The logarithmic approach is indeed something that comes up as soon as you have a multiplicative constraint and some size restraint, because the multiplicativity blows up any small deviation from the expected result.

Comment: @Leullame Actually, the most difficult thing for me was to notice the simple argument for $d_m<d_{m-1}$ because I was not sure what additional condition I was looking for.